# Detect and replace unpaired markdown symbols, not changing paired symbols

Tags: java, regex

I have this

```
Hello \**how are you\**? I'm fine*
```

need to get this

```
Hello *how are you*? I'm fine\*
```

I can get

```
Hello *how are you*? I'm fine*
```

but then I'm lost, since `s.replace("*', "\*")` is not an option

Basically the problem is about the matching (paired) * needing to be replaced with *, while unpaired * needing to be escaped.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? Some problems may have multiple solutions. Please post the piece of code that you used to obtain that result.

Comment: @Razvan the code uses other libraries and is a mess in general. Suffice to say, I start out with `Hello **how are you**? I'm fine*`, then use another lib to escape paired markdown symbols. In the end I need to get `Hello *how are you*? I'm fine\*`, no matter the means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to split the string in words, then find out which words have unpaired '*'.

```
String text1 = "*This* is **my** text*";
String[] words = text1.split(" ");
for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++){
    int count = words[i].length() - words[i].replace("*", "").length(); // count the number of '*'
    if(count%2 != 0){ // if it's not paired we can replace with '\*'
        words[i] = words[i].replace("*", "\\*");
    }
}
System.out.println(String.join(" ", words));

Which prints out: *This* is **my** text\*
```

Comment: hm it doesn't seem to account for whether * are paired or not - it would replace regardless. Say this `*This* is **my** text* ` gets replaced with `\*This\* is *my* text\* `, while it should be `*This* is *my* text\* `

Comment: That's why I asked for a bit of context. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Someone helped me out with this:

```
String text1 = "*This is **my** text* ";
System.out.println(text1.replaceAll("(?<=[^*\\\\]|\\A)[*](?=[^*\\\\]|\\z)", "\\\\*"));
```

which prints `\*This is **my** text\*`

Comment: Okay, this doesn't work with `*This is **my** text* and **`, need it to return `*This is **my** text* and \**`, but it returns `\*This is *my* text\* and **`